# Violation of the second law of thermodynamics with thermal radiation

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

If we have two cubic cavities both with perfectly reflecting walls, one much large than the other, both with a blackbody in them, then when they are both in thermal equilibrium with their surroundings and are at the same temperature the much larger box will permit a range of frequencies that the smaller one won't.
Then if we use an optical filter that only allows low wavelength light to pass, we could allow light, and so energy, to go from one box to the other and we'd have a net flow of energy between two systems that are both at thermal equilibrium and at the same temperature.

Does this not violate the second law of thermodynamics?

To me it sounds reasonable that this should be possible, however the argument that should allow one to generalise Planck's law of thermal radiation, derived specifically for a cubic cavity with reflecting walls, to cavities of arbitrary shape and made out of arbitrary material relies on this being impossible:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_law_of_thermal_radiation

I'd be very happy to read your insights.

Comment: The filter will radiate.

Comment: Would it not radiate equally into both cavities so that it cannot cancel the net flow of energy?

Comment: > *"we could allow light, and so energy, to go from one box to the other"* But would light/energy go from one box to another? The smaller box won't support long wavelength radiation.

Comment: Recently I have asked a related question but got no convincing (me)  reply https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/572027/black-body-radiation-and-thermal-equilibration. The most relevant comment was by @BowlOfRed "The concept of a temperature is one of thermal equilibrium. That is happening constantly in any body that we consider to have reached thermal equilibrium. So any energy input at one wavelength thermalizes to others." but I think this needs a lot more detail how.

Comment: @JánLalinský "won't support" means that the energy in the frequency cannot build up arbitrarily due to accumulation of thermal radiation by it being reflected inside the cavity so that the frequency can behave like a degree of freedom. Once a long wavelength frequency has accumulated energy in the big box, it can still get into the small box via the optical filter. It has to do with not being able to build up, not with being unable to exist in the cavity at all.